# How can I keyframe various specific properties of multiple objects?

Tags: keyframes

Is there a way to keyframe the same property across multiple objects? I know pressing I allows you to keyframe certain things like position, location and scale, but what if you want to keyframe a specific property? Ie z location of multiple objects, light power of multiple objects.

[This add-on](https://youtu.be/tFnUI_LGmMI) addresses my question, but isn't there a native way to do these things? I'm a Cinema 4D user and it seems like this would be a basic thing you'd want that shouldn't require a paid add-on, so I wonder if I need to un-learn the Cinema way of accomplishing these things?

Comment: so just that i understand you right: you are complaining about a free software where the special functionality you are used to, is not in and you won't pay 10 Euro for an add-on, but you have paid several 100 Euro for the other software? Some people i will never understand....If you don't wanna pay, you can write your own add-on for free ;)

Comment: Just for your last question: Yes, you will have to un-learn the "Cinema way" not only for accomplishing these things, but others as well. A problem which can happen with other software, too.

Comment: @Chris lol, I'm complaining? I'm trying to better understand Blender. No, you clearly don't understand, given your snotty response. It's not a "special" functionality, it's an incredibly basic function used in Cinema 4D and After Effects. In the future. don't even bother replying if this is your idea of help.